# wxpython: close the frame but no the script

Tags: python, wxpython, frame

I have a script, this call to a wx.app
when I close the wx.app this close the script, why ?

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
    ...

class BoaApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.main = Frame.create(None)
        self.main.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.main)
        return True
def main():
    application = BoaApp(0)
    application.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please, show us some (of the relevant parts of your) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `app.MainLoop()` the script goes into a loop which runs the app. When you close the app the loop exits and any code after the call of `app.MainLoop()` then executes. If there isn't anything left to do, the script will end.